# How to properly manage "one time" event with angularjs and bootstrap's badges?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, badge

I work with angularjs and bootstrap (I'm a beginner with angular). I have a lot of `list-group` in my app and I need to display a `badge` on each of them if the user hasn't click on the item yet. Once clicked for the first time the badge is removed (and should appear again even if the user refresh the page).

Since it's really recurrent in the app, I don't know of to properly do this...
I don't want to work with tons of boolean or session storage to check if the user has click or not. Do you see a pretty way to do it with angular?

FYI, this is my HTML right now:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a ng-repeat="item in itemList" 
       ng-click="select(item)" 
       ng-class="{active: selected === item}"
       class="list-group-item">
        {{item.name}} <span class="badge">{{item.badge}}</span> 
    </a>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.itemList = [{
            name: 'Lorem',
            badge: 'New'
        }, {
            name: 'Ipsum',
            badge: 'New'
        }];

        $scope.select = function (item) {
            $scope.selected = item;
        };
    }
]);
```

The property *badge* should became empty at the first click and stay empty even if the user leave the app.

Comment: When the element is clicked what  do you exactly want? clear the span class badge? remove the span.badge element?

Comment: Why manage all the list items client side? If you are constrained that way I suggest relying on browser local storage...

Comment: @borjagómez I just want to not display the badge for the user. I tested with `badge: ''` and it works. But I don't know how to automatize it.

Comment: @deostroll It's some "business requirements", most of the data should be managed on client-side. Should I manage each item with a 'status' to know if it has been already visited or not?

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended you do this via some database or some third party sessions provider that complements your web application.

Alternatively, if you are stuck to implementing this on the client browser you can utilize the browser's local storage.

I am only showing here the angular service implemented that stores the stuff to local storage. The rest of the code is in the plunk below:

```
  .service('todosvc', function($window) {
    var stg = $window.localStorage.getItem('todos');
    if(!stg || (typeof stg === 'string' && stg.length === 0)) {
      todos = []
    }
    else {
      todos = angular.fromJson(stg);  
    }

    this.get = function() {
      return todos;
    };

    this.update = function() {
      $window.localStorage.setItem('todos', angular.toJson(todos));
    };
  })
```

Now if you happen to refresh the page, you will find that the same items remain.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nvDmA9ipCNhL2DD14AGz?p=preview